# Encoding problem with caption in Imagemagick on php

Tags: php, encoding, imagemagick, caption

I'm adding some heading in Russian on the image using newPseudoImage and CAPTION.
Heading can have some entities like `&nbsp;` `&mdash;` etc, so I clean it with html_entity_decode.
In some cases it works well, but in some cases text after decoded entity goes in wrong encoding, like that:

[look at second line - there is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dTD5.jpg)

Please, help me to find the solution.

If I use annotateImage - everything is nice.
If I use newPseudoImage and LABEL - everything is nice.
The problem appears only with newPseudoImage and CAPTION (but I have to CAPTION, cause I need to scale my headings depending on their length).

At the same time I have to use these entities in headings (i.e. `&nbsp;` to avoid wrapping of the dash to the next line).

Some headings shows nice:
'Путешествие в Карелию' - is fine, but 'Нуорунен в Карелии' - shows with error.

My code:

```
$postTitle = 'Нуорунен в&nbsp;Карелии';
$postTitle = html_entity_decode($postTitle);

$mainImage = new Imagick('source.jpg');
$title = new Imagick();
$colorize = new Imagick();
        
$mainImage->setImageCompressionQuality(85);

$title->setBackgroundColor('transparent');
        
$title->setFont('/fonts/roboto-slab_semibold.ttf');
$title->setGravity(imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
$title->newPseudoImage( 780, 480, "CAPTION:" . $postTitle );
    
$colorize->newImage(1, 1, new ImagickPixel('#f8bb00'));
$title->clutImage($colorize);
$colorize->destroy();
    
$mainImage->compositeImage($title, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 210, 110);
        
$mainImage->writeImage('image.jpg');
```

Comment: I think you have stumbled upon a bug in ImageMagick. I tested this with the convert function in bash to rule out any php involvement and could reproduce the scenario perfectly. I created following GitHub bug: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/4305 
I'll keep you posted on the outcome.

Comment: Suddenly =) Thank you so much, will wait for the news.

Comment: This has been [confirmed as a bug][1] in ImageMagick. As you can see in the thread, a beta release will be made available later but probably it will take quite a while to get this into the PHP extension through the regular channels. I can't really help with a workaround either. Is it possible to perform your own checks to see if the text might fit on one line and perform your own line breaks on 'regular spaces' if it doesn't?

Comment: Maybe your theory is right: it looks like the problem take place only when 'non-breaking space' wraps some preceding word on the next line. I coudn't produce any case where 'non-breaking space' cause the problem in the middle of line.

But anyway it looks for me like some heisenbug - in some cases everything is nice even when 'non-breaking space' wraps some preceding word on the next line (like 'Путешествие в&nbsp;Карелию'), but in some cases I've got the problem.